# Cannot make Owin Authentication Challenge with ApiController

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-apicontroller

I cannot get the `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge` to work extending a `ApiController` it just doesnt do anything, not even an error. I just get the output ":("

What am i doing wrong can this even be achieved? this is a Web API and the `Controller` RegisterRoutes is causing problems with my custom routes

It works fine when I extend `Controller`

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
    }
```

It does not work when i extend `ApiController`

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("signin")]
        public IHttpActionResult SignIn()
        {
            if (User == null || User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
                    .Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() {RedirectUri = "/"}, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                return Ok(":(");
            }

            return Ok(":)");
        }
    }
```

This wont allow my `ApiController` routing to work

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
```